# how to fetch user location in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to show the user region and country from IP address but I am not been able to get it. Every time when I am passing the IP address to different API I am getting please enter the valid IP address. I am doing this using shortcode inside the **functions.php** and I am accessing the **shortcode** in the **footer.php** but it is not working.

This is the code which I have write in functions.php

```
function user_region() { 
       $ip = "27.255.58.21";
       $http = wp_remote_get( 'https://ipinfo.io/{$ip}/json' );
       $data = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $http );
       $result=print_r($data);


  return '<div class="user-region">'.$data->country_name.'</div>';  

    }  

add_shortcode("get-user-region", "user_region");
```

this is what i am getting in the footer

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempting to use variable interpolation using single quotes. That will not work. Replace the single quotes with double quotes. Using double quotes allows for variable expansion, but single quotes doesn't.

Try this:

```
$http = wp_remote_get("https://ipinfo.io/{$ip}/json");
```

Or, if you insist on using single quotes:

```
$http = wp_remote_get('https://ipinfo.io/' . $ip . '/json');
```

Comment: can i try with some other api if you can make the answer with some other api because it is showing that i have exceed the limit

Comment: Use any API you wish. Variable interpolation is a language feature. You were using it incorrectly, hence why it wasn't working for you. Use double quotes.

Comment: Array ( [headers] => Requests_Utility_CaseInsensitiveDictionary Object ( [data:protected] => Array ( [server] => nginx [date] => Fri, 15 Feb 2019 20:37:17 GMT [content-type] => text/html ) ) [body] =>
403 Forbidden
nginx
[response] => Array ( [code] => 403 [message] => Forbidden ) [cookies] => Array ( ) [filename] => [http_response] => WP_HTTP_Requests_Response Object ( [response:protected] => Requests_Response Object ( [body] =>
403 Forbidden

Comment: Please do not post code in comments.  Edit / update your original question with code that is formatted in a stack snippet.